Regional Rank Choice Voting on Maps
So, I made an algorithm to do rank choice voting on regions. Based on where you are, votes for candidates are stored in specific position in each list that labels the region. If there is a tie, then it looks at the adjacent cells. If there is a tie, it goes to the next one... And if there is a tie for the leaders for the entire region, a winner is randomly chosen.
For Voronois, it gives an output like:

with the code:
RegionalRankChoiceVoting[numPoints_Integer, start_Integer, cf_ : ColorData["CoffeeTones"]] := 
 Module[{findWinner, polygons, graph, distances, centerOfMasses, randomLists, distanceGroups, voronoiMesh, graphic, flattenedLists, winner},
  
  (* Define the function to find the winner *)
  findWinner[lists_List] := Module[{winners, currentMax, uniqueMax},
    winners = Range[Length[First[lists]]];
    
    Do[
      currentMax = Max[lists[[i, winners]]];
      
      winners = Position[lists[[i]], currentMax][[All, 1]];
      
      If[Length[winners] == 1,
        Return[winners[[1]]];
      ];
    , {i, Length[lists]}];

    RandomChoice[winners]
  ];
  
  points = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {numPoints, 2}];
  voronoiMesh = VoronoiMesh[points];
  
  polygons = MeshPrimitives[voronoiMesh, 2];
  
  graph = MeshConnectivityGraph[voronoiMesh, 2];
  distances = GraphDistance[graph, VertexList[graph][[start]]];
  
  centerOfMasses = MeshPrimitives[voronoiMesh, 2] /. Polygon[pts_] :> Mean[pts];
  
  listLength = 5;
  randomLists = Table[RandomInteger[{0, 100}, listLength], {Length[polygons]}];
  
  (* Group the cells by distance from the start *)
  distanceGroups = GatherBy[SortBy[Transpose[{distances, randomLists}], First], First][[All, All, 2]];
  
  graphic = Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], 
    MapThread[{cf[#2/Max[distances]], #1} &, {polygons, distances}],
    Table[Text[Style[randomLists[[i]], Bold, Black], centerOfMasses[[i]]], {i, Length[polygons]}]
  }, ImageSize -> 1000];
  
  flattenedLists = Flatten[distanceGroups, 1];
  
  winner = findWinner[flattenedLists];
  
  {graphic, distanceGroups, winner}
 ]

(* Generate a set of random points for the Voronoi diagram *)
numPoints = 50;
start = RandomInteger[{1, numPoints}];
result = RegionalRankChoiceVoting[numPoints, start];

result[[1]]
Print["Election Results: ", result[[2]]]
Print["Winner: Candidate ", result[[3]]]

Where if there is a tie, it moves onto the next one. We can do something similar with maps, I am certain. But I wanted suggestions on how to go about it because currently the code is a bit slow and I was also wondering if I can do it more tersely with maps. I tend to think too procedurally for Mathematica.
Here is an example with Laos, but not with all the extra coloring and doing the election results.

that was generated by the code:
divisions = Entity["Country", "Laos"]["AdministrativeDivisions"];
provincePolygons = EntityValue[divisions, "Polygon"];
provinceCenters = RegionCentroid /@ provincePolygons;

listLength = 5;
randomLists = Table[RandomInteger[{0, 100}, listLength], {Length[provinceCenters]}];

textLabels = Style[#, Bold, Black] & /@ randomLists;

GeoGraphics[
  {
    {GeoStyling["OutlineMap"], {EdgeForm[Black], Opacity[1], Polygon[divisions]}},
    MapThread[Text[#1, #2] &, {textLabels, provinceCenters}]
  },
  GeoRange -> {{13, 23}, {100, 108}}, (* Adjusted to focus on Laos *)
  GeoRangePadding -> None,
  GeoBackground -> None,
  ImageSize -> 1000
]

It would be wonderful if there was a single way to do it for both or many types of regions with the same code.

Instead of MeshConnectivityGraph, you can use the following: Cluster graph of bordered countries?.

@TegLouis, if Domen's idea is a a success - please post updated code here.

@Domen The problem with that code is we are looking at bordering administrative divisions rather than countries. There is "BorderingStates" and "BorderingCounties" to use with AdministrativeDivisionData, but that is only for the U.S.

I don't think there is anything built in to do find bordering administrative regions within any country. Currently, the next best option is to use GeoNearest like in azerbajdzan's answer to a different question.
